# Value of a bar in a graph

Tags: r

I made a thread about this earlier although it got closed since I was unclear. I will try to be more clear now.

What I'm wondering is, if you enter my code into Rstudio, it will give you a graph. On the x-axis there are 6 bars (6 different states), and on the y-axis is the frequency 0-300. All I can see is that state 1 is somewhere in-between 0 and 50. Is there any code that can let me exactly what value state 1 and the others states have?

Here is a matrix:

```
spec_sim <- function(x){ 
  u <- runif(1) 
  if(x==0){ if(u < 0.5){ y <- 3 
    } else{ 
      y <- 5 
    } 
  } else if(x==1){
    if(u<0.1){ 
      y <- 0 
    } else if(u < 0.1 + 0.1){ 
      y <- 1 
    } else if(u < 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.4){ 
      y <- 3 
    } else{ 
      y <- 5 
    } 
  } else if(x==2){ 
    if(u<0.2){ 
      y <- 1 
    } else if(u < 0.2 + 0.2){ 
      y <- 2 
    } else if(u < 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.3){ 
      y <- 3 
    } else{ 
      y <- 5 
    } 
  } else if(x==3){ 
    if(u<0.3){ 
      y <- 2 
    } else if(u < 0.3 + 0.5){ 
      y <- 3 
    } else{ 
      y <- 5 
    } 
  } else if(x==4){ 
    if(u<0.4){ 
      y <- 3 
    } else{ 
      y <- 4 
    } 
  } else if(x==5){ 
    if(u<0.4){ 
      y <- 4 
    } else{ 
      y <- 5 
    }
  } 
  y
}

set.seed(1) 
results <- numeric(1001)
for(i in 2:length(results)){
  results[i]<- spec_sim(results[i - 1]) 
}
results <- results[-1]

barplot(table(results), xlab="states", ylab="frequency", 
        main="1000 simuleringar av en Markovkedja")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you format your `spec_sim` function. It is hard to figure out.

Comment: I can't get your code to run. Probably you need to add a lot of line breaks and indentation. Anyways, `table(results)` probably contains the numbers you are looking for. If you didn't write this code yourself, consider reading `?table` and the examples there before taking on such a complicated case.

Comment: Check out the `ggplot2` package.  It's very easy to do using `ggplot()`. Here's a link for data labels in ggplot: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_text.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify the value in an active plotting device (window), you use [?identify](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/identify.html).  Since the data to be plotted were from a table that was created (but not saved to an object) within the plotting command, you need to enter that for the `x` and `labels` arguments to the function.  Once you run the command, the mouse pointer will display as a plus over the plotting device.  Then you just click on the bar you want.  Consider:

```
identify(table(results), labels=table(results))
```

[image]

The value for `1` is evidently `26`.

This is a very general method for getting values from a plot.  Of course, you can also just inspect the underlying data object.  That is more straightforward in this case:

```
table(results)
# results
#   0   1   2   3   4   5 
#   4  26 112 306 296 256
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, it was exactly what i was looking for. I do have another question, the data is from a markov chain where we start in state 5 and go 1000 steps. Is there a possibility to see how many times we we went to state 5 before we were in state 1?

Comment: The issue of how to inspect intermediate states of a Markov model is a different one. You should ask that as a new question. It will also depend on what code / functions you are using.